# iOS Assign ID to something?

Tags: ios

I am sorry for the newbish question, but I am transitioning over from traditional programming like PHP to learning iOS. What I am trying to understand is, how to assign a unique ID to an iOS interface element.
For example, in HTML, you could do:

```
<input type="button" id="button123" />
```

and then: (For example, with jQuery)

```
$("#button123").slideDown();
```

in iOS, how would I assign a unique handler to an input or other item? I have seen things like

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *myImage;
```

But where would I put that, and how would I "Assign" it to said imageview?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you creating the interface (code / XIB / storyboard) and what do you want to use the identifier for (set an image / differentiate between multiple image views)?

Comment: I am creating it with a Story Board. I want to use the ID to be able to resize an image in code, and set it's X and Y coordinates.

Comment: You don't use an "id". You use the ivar you created and setup as an outlet.

Comment: Have a look at ["Creating and Connecting an Outlet"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles-connections_bindings/CreatingOutlet.html) in the "Interface Builder Help" for a tutorial how to create outlet connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make your interface in Interface Builder (select a XIB file) (this is a graphical view like a browser rendering your HTLM).

Then, in your ViewController, in the header (.h) file, add properties like

```
@property (assign) IBOutlet UIImageView* aUniqueVarName;
```

Where you make define a link from a variable 'aUniqueVarName (like variables in PHP) on a class, linked to your interface elements. In Interface builder, you'll need to link them via control-click, to assign the correct variables to the responding graphical elements.

UIImageViews for imageviews, UILabels for labels etc. then, in the code, you can use the variable-names, eg myLabel.stringValue etc.

Comment: Or use the Assistant Editor in Xcode and Control-Drag the UI element onto the .h file (or the class extension part of the .m file). That will create the property and the connection.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an ID, In the example you posted:

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *myImage;
```

`myImage` is unique , the compiler would not let you duplicate that name.

Comment: Yes, but how would I go about telling the compiler which of my multiple imageviews it belongs to?

Comment: @DarthCaniac in your implementation file `.m` you would just use myImage directly, in other word the variable name is your "ID"